# Add ApiController with token authentication/authorization to existing ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, token

I am working on an existing ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 project and now trying to build a mobile application around it. For this purpose I introduced a new ApiController class to handle all logic needed by the mobile app. My intention was initially to just use the same login method which is used by the MVC part of the project which turned out not to be working as expected (the login succeeds but on further requests, the application returns the default Login page). So now my approach would be to use Token authorization for just one ApiController. Did anyone ever have a similar scenario and could help me out with an example on how to do so, maybe?

I'm guessing I could keep my currently working login method and just return some kind of token which is then kept by the client to be sent with all further requests.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the API Controller handles the login for the mobile app and the rest is done by the MVC Controllers?

Comment: No, actually I want to provide all necessary data and actions through this one extra ApiController (for the mobile app). And specifically for that controller I thought of using a token based authentication system, which returns a token after an initial Login. I hope that clarifies and am sorry for being unclear before.

Comment: Could you provide some code? It´s hard to say out of the box what maybe cause the problem.